# npm errors after git merge with conflicts

Tags: git, reactjs, npm, package.json

So, I am using React, create-react-app to be precise.

Main question: How do I get React back to work? I am pretty much a beginner with npm / React, so I don't know where to begin troubleshooting this.

After manually merging a branch that was made 20 days ago, which caused some merge conflicts, I get the following error when starting up the React dev server (npm start).

One of the merge conflicts was in package.json, so that might be where the problem originates from. I'll post my package.json file at the bottom.

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'styled-components' in 'C:\Users\riksch\Documents\MEGAsync\projects\Current\greenery-marketplace\frontend\src'
```

So, I tried re-installing it. Still the same error.

Then I googled some, and found a way to list my installed packages, so I ran:

```
npm list --depth=0
```

This shows some errors:

```
+-- axios@0.18.0
+-- jquery@3.3.1
+-- js-cookie@2.2.0
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@16.2.0
+-- react-dom@16.2.0
+-- react-form@3.5.5
+-- react-intl@2.4.0
+-- react-route@1.0.3
+-- react-router-dom@4.2.2
+-- react-scripts@1.1.1
+-- react-strap@0.0.1
+-- reactstrap@6.0.1
`-- UNMET DEPENDENCY styled-components@^3.3.2

npm ERR! peer dep missing: react@^0.13.3 || ^0.14.0-rc1, required by react-route@1.0.3
npm ERR! missing: styled-components@^3.3.2, required by frontend@0.1.0
npm ERR! peer dep missing: ajv@^6.0.0, required by ajv-keywords@3.1.0
```

Then I tried updating npm, hoping that would help.

```
npm update -g --verbose
```

I also tried putting packages in different orders in the package.json file. That didn't seem to help. Then I tried uninstalling styled-components, but that gives another error:

```
npm ERR! Unexpected string in JSON at position 332738

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\riksch\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-06-19T19_56_05_969Z-debug.log
```

Trying to install styled-components again gives me this:

npm ERR! Unexpected string in JSON at position 332738

```
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\riksch\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-06-19T19_56_21_076Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\riksch\Documents\MEGAsync\projects\Current\greenery-marketplace\frontend>
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-form": "^3.5.5",
    "react-intl": "^2.4.0",
    "react-route": "^1.0.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.1",
    "styled-components": "^3.3.2",
    "react-strap": "0.0.1",
    "reactstrap": "^6.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

package.json with unresolved merge conflict:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-form": "^3.5.5",
    "react-intl": "^2.4.0",
    "react-route": "^1.0.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.1",
<<<<<<< HEAD
    "styled-components": "^3.3.2"
=======
    "react-strap": "0.0.1",
>>>>>>> contact-form
    "reactstrap": "^6.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Now I don't want to mess things up even more. So I'm posting my question here:

**How do I get React back to work? I am pretty much a beginner with npm / React, so I don't know where to begin troubleshooting this.**

Comment: The errors show that you have unmet peer dependencies, `react@16.2.0`, `styled-components@^3.3.2`, and `ajv@^6.0.0`. You should try installing the dependencies manually. From your project directory: `npm install --save react@16.2.0 styled-components ajv`

Comment: Thanks, but doint that gives me the following error: npm ERR! Unexpected string in JSON at position 332738

Comment: does it tell you which file the error is in? my blind guess would be maybe you changed your package.json file and there is a syntax error there. Did you fix the merge conflict that you show in your question?

Comment: Hi bitwitch, thank you for thinking along. I did solve the problem. I posted my solution below.

Comment: Was there also a merge conflict inside the package-lock.json? Your high character number inside your error seems to suggest this

Answer (score 0):

Edit: looking back at this post, after becoming more experienced I clearly see what the issue must be. The `package.json` contains lines that are the result of an unfinished merge conflict, and should look something like this:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-form": "^3.5.5",
    "react-intl": "^2.4.0",
    "react-route": "^1.0.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.1",
    "styled-components": "^3.3.2"
    "react-strap": "0.0.1",
    "reactstrap": "^6.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

I removed these lines, as they have nothing to do with the `package.json`, but are added temporarily, I think by GIT, and are still in the file because the merge didn't finish.

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
=======
>>>>>>> contact-form
```

These lines cause the error `Unexpected string in JSON at position 332738`.

---

This is the old solution, from me in 2018:

I have solved this error, although not in a very elegant way I guess.

I simply created a new React enviromnent, using 'create-react-app'. I then used the old package.json to install all the needed packages / dependencies in the new environment.

After that I copied the /public and /src directories from the old environment to the new environment (overwriting the directories in the new React environment).

Everything worked just fine after that.